# If using a UISearchBar in a storyboard, how do you associate that with a UISearchController?

Tags: ios, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

When a `UISearchController` is created, it automatically creates a `UISearchBar`:

```
let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
searchController.searchBar.whatever = whatever
```

However if I add a `UISearchBar` to the storyboard and connect it as an outlet, its going to be a separate object from the one created as part of the `UISearchController`.

My question therefore is:  **is there a way of making `UISearchController.searchBar` the searchBar in the storyboard so that its attributes can be altered within the storyboard rather than programatically?**

If not, then whats the point of there being a `UISearchBar` in the storyboard? Would you ever use just a `UISearchBar` on its own, i.e. not used with a `UISearchController`?